# Are we not always working in an infinite number of dimensions?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

My question basically boils down to the fact that when dealing with 2 dimensions, $x$ and $y$, are we not technically also dealing with every other dimension too, just leaving them blank as there are infinite solutions, like with points on a polar plane, we might leave something in the form of $(5,\frac{3\pi}{2}+2\pi)$ if we wanted to represent the infinite solutions.

So, are we not basically dealing with a situation where if we are looking at a point, it's really an infinitely dimensional plane where we are only focusing on a specific set of planes. For example, if we were to be dealing with a 3 dimensional point, like $(3,4,5)$ are we not really dealing with something in the form of $(3,4,5,w,...)$ where "$...$" represents all other dimensions, and we're only narrowing down on the specific location of the infinite planes on 3 axis?

And, if that is true, then when we define a "line" on the $(x,y)$ axis, if we were to define it as something in the form of $y=x+2$, how are we not just creating a new plane or dimension to represent that. How is it that it is known that it is related to the initial $y$ plane.

I hope I'm making sense but this was kind of hard to explain my thought process.

Thanks for any clarification!

Comment: I see a problem here: what do you call "all the other dimensions"? In mathematics, there is no "universal world" which contains all the possible dimensions. (Existence of such a world would lead to set theory paradoxes.) Thus, we always define the "world" in which we work (with $2, 3$, (countably) infinitely many etc. dimensions) up-front, and then we work in it. Using the notion of a function/map you can link those worlds, so for example from $3$-dimensional world into a $2$-dimensional world you can have a *projection* ($\pi(x,y,z)=(x,y)$) which is one of those "linear" maps, widely studied.

Comment: You also remind me of what physicists call "compactification": apparently, we might not live in a $4$-dimensional world but in an $11$-dimensional one: $7$ of the dimensions may be really tiny, and instead of every point $(x,y,z,t)$ there really is a whole (tiny) *manifold* /"surface" (parameterized by $7$ more variables) "at that point". (Or, at least some theories can be developed based on such thinking, apparently! This is as far as my popular science understanding goes...)

Comment: @StinkingBishop "I see a problem here: what do you call 'all the other dimensions'": if we were to consider 2 dimensions, xy, there still would exist a z dimension that we leave out as we are only interested in where x and y exist, but z would still exist, it just would not be considered, like this apparently 2d line [link](https://imgur.com/VFrOh50), could be expanded to consider 3d space [link](https://imgur.com/a/u8TNn8D) where for every $y$ value exists this line, it just isn't considered

Comment: This is not a problem: viewing a $2$-dimensional space as a projection of a $3$-dimensional space. I only object to the suggestion that there is some given infinitely-dimensional world. As known from the set theory, for every infinity there is a bigger infinity, and there is no set of all infinities. So you need to decide up-front where (on the "ladder of infinities") you will stop.

Answer (score 2):

To put it concisely, no, not really.

I think the source of your confusion is the convention to define a subset of $\Bbb{R}^2$ or $\Bbb{R}^3$ (i.e. $2$ or $3$ dimensional space) in terms of an equation in terms of $x$, $y$, and $z$. For example, the line in $\Bbb{R}^2$, going through the origin, of slope $-1/2$ is sometimes presented as an equation
$$x + 2y = 0.$$
However, this is something of an abuse of notation. An equation isn't the same thing as the set of points it represents; it's just a statement, depending on unknown variables $x$ and $y$, that is either true or false (depending on the value of $x$ and $y$).

That said, we often use an equation as a kind of shorthand to refer to the *set of points* (in a space understood by context) which satisfy this equation. If we are talking about $\Bbb{R}^2$, i.e. the Cartesian plane, then the above equation is understood to reference the set:
$$\{(x, y) \in \Bbb{R}^2 : x + 2y = 0\}.$$
However, if we mix up the context a bit, and we were talking about $\Bbb{R}^3$, the same equation could refer to the (vertical) plane:
$$\{(x, y, z) \in \Bbb{R}^3 : x + 2y = 0\}.$$
This is a different set, in a different space, but both are referred to by the same equation. If it is not clear which space we are talking about, and hence which of the above sets is being referred to, then simply writing the equation is ambiguous. The author should make it crystal clear which space they're working in.

Also note the assumption that $x$ refers to the first coordinate of a point, and $y$ refers to the second. This need not necessarily be the case, but it is assumed by convention (which is a kind of context). Without this convention, our equation could just as easily be referring to
$$\{(y, x) \in \Bbb{R}^2 : x + 2y = 0\},$$
or in other words,
$$\{(x, y) \in \Bbb{R}^2 : 2x + y = 0\},$$
which is a different line altogether!

So, no, we are not always working in infinite dimensions. You will typically be working in finite dimensions (probably $\Bbb{R}^2$ or $\Bbb{R}^3$ if you're looking at equations involving $x$, $y$, and/or $z$). Equations should be understood to refer to sets in a space that is clear from context, and if the space is unclear, then so is the equation.

Comment: This is a wonderful answer. I am still a bit confused about the statement "You will typically be working in finite dimensions" because while I can agree that it is true that we are typically working in finite quantity of dimensions, how it could not be considered, however, that there still exist infinite dimensions that we are simply not taking into account, and just leaving them as a variable quantity that may be left unresolved as we're not looking into that dimension. Am I wrong in that understanding, that even if we are only looking at xy, xyz still exists?

Comment: Whenever we do work with vectors, we do so in a vector space. A vector space is a very precise mathematical notion that you will learn about in university if you do linear algebra, but for our purposes, it's a "universe" of vectors that you're working with. Before you do any operations with vectors, you need to agree on the vector space you're working in. Now, infinite-dimensional vector spaces do exist, and you can consider lines and planes in them, but typically you'll be working in $\Bbb{R}^2$ or $\Bbb{R}^3$. In $\Bbb{R}^2$, $z$ doesn't "exist", as in there is no third coordinate.

Comment: Okay, so if I'm understanding you correctly, infinite-dimensional vector spaces exist, but we don't consider them because we're only focused on a particular set of dimensions?

Comment: @Tartarus13 That's mostly right. It's worth pointing out that "dimensions" are not something that exist independently of the spaces that they're in. That is, vector spaces are not simply a collection of "dimensions" bundled together. Dimension in a vector space is simply a number (or cardinal, more precisely) describing the number of independent direction vectors you can collect. It is not correct to think of, say, the $x$-axis in $\Bbb{R}^2$ as a "dimension", or to think of it as the same thing as the $x$-axis in $\Bbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @Tartarus13 We have a conventional way of "embedding" $\Bbb{R}^2$ into $\Bbb{R}^3$: specifically we take the points of the form $(x, y, 0)$ and identify them with $(x, y)$. But, while it's tempting to think that $(x, y, 0)$ and $(x, y)$ are actually the same thing, they are not! They behave similarly with respect to vector addition and scalar multiplication, but an ordered pair like $(x, y)$ is not the same as an ordered triple like $(x, y, 0)$. We treat them as though they are the same as a matter of convenience, but they are actually distinct objects.

Comment: Infinitely-dimensional spaces have their proper use, and we often work with them. Quantum physics, for example, makes heavy use of infinitely-dimensional Hilbert spaces. Those are also indispensable for the theory of solving differential equations. The dimensions may not be "spacial", so to speak: they may correspond to *contributions* (of a particular solution of some equation to the overall solution), or to *probabilities* (of a measurement to be found in a particular subspace) etc. My point is, when working in an infinitely-dimensional vector space, we rarely need to descend... (TBC)

Comment: (Cont'd)... to the finite-dimensional case, and the descent is not as simple as doing away with (most of) the co-ordinates. (Note in quantum physics, for every *value* of $x$ co-ordinate you define an *operator* ("multiply by $x$") on the actual infinitely-dimensional space, and this operator is somehow related with where the particle you are describing will be found on the $x$ axis (and with which probability)).

Comment: @StinkingBishop I should point out that when I'm saying "typically $\Bbb{R}^2$ or $\Bbb{R}^3$, I'm specifically talking to the OP. I don't mean to assume that every single person works with $\Bbb{R}^2$ and $\Bbb{R}^3$ most of the time. I myself am writing up a PhD thesis dealing with arbitrary infinite-dimensional real inner product spaces.